# Django redirect user before logout

Tags: django, redirect, logout

I want to redirect the user to a page where he can see some statistic datas before logout. So what exactly I want is when he clicks on the logout button then first to show him that page ex: `localhost:8000/statistic/` and after if he clicked on another button on that page then logout him.
Now I am using Django's LogoutView:

```
class LogoutView(SuccessURLAllowedHostsMixin, TemplateView):
    """
    Log out the user and display the 'You are logged out' message.
    """
    next_page = None
    redirect_field_name = REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
    template_name = 'registration/logged_out.html'
    extra_context = None

    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        auth_logout(request)
        next_page = self.get_next_page()
        if next_page:
            # Redirect to this page until the session has been cleared.
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next_page)
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Logout may be done via POST."""
        return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_next_page(self):
        if self.next_page is not None:
            next_page = resolve_url(self.next_page)
        elif settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL:
            next_page = resolve_url(settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL)
        else:
            next_page = self.next_page

        if (self.redirect_field_name in self.request.POST or
                self.redirect_field_name in self.request.GET):
            next_page = self.request.POST.get(
                self.redirect_field_name,
                self.request.GET.get(self.redirect_field_name)
            )
            url_is_safe = is_safe_url(
                url=next_page,
                allowed_hosts=self.get_success_url_allowed_hosts(),
                require_https=self.request.is_secure(),
            )
            # Security check -- Ensure the user-originating redirection URL is
            # safe.
            if not url_is_safe:
                next_page = self.request.path
        return next_page

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        current_site = get_current_site(self.request)
        context.update({
            'site': current_site,
            'site_name': current_site.name,
            'title': _('Logged out'),
            **(self.extra_context or {})
        })
        return context
```

I think I have to override this View in my code, but I am a little bit confused about the steps, witch method do I have to override, how it should be.

Comment: Rather than overriding the LogoutView, you should simply name your button **show statistics** or maybe **logout** which refers to your statistics page with URL ```localhost:8000/statistic/``` After this you can add a real Logout button.

Comment: just create a button that redirect the user to that staticdata template and than use the logout method inside that template.